# The best way to use controllers with cached data in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created .Net Core application which consists of 8 controllers and 12 repositories. The application lacks speed and needs to reduce the number of requests sending to SQL database.

All controllers create a new connection to load data via repositories when receiving a request from a user. I believe the best way to improve the core is to cache all data and store it in a repository's memory

Currently, all repositories have a list of cached results, which is populated during an initialization (I just call `SELECT * FROM table` and put data to the list)

The problem is that controllers store different instances of the same repositories, where each repository has own cached list. It works but not ideal because cache needs to be updated and cached lists need to be stored across all controllers

Do you have any ideas on how to share cached data across controllers in .Net Core?

Comment: Using a `static` or `Lazy<T>` class for the cache would probably be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would retain instance-based dependency injection for the repositories, but I would make sure the repositories are injected a singleton cache that they use to retrieve the data. This way you ensure that each repository instance accesses the same cache. Not sure if you're using IMemoryCache [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.0), but it's a good example.

Comment: Hey denat, thank you for the link and idea - I will try to implement your approach

Comment: You should use `IDistributedCache` instead of `IMemoryCache`. By default, a `MemoryDistributedCache` provider is injected for `IDistributedCache`, so the end result is the same: caching in memory, but using `IDistributedCache` frees you up to sub-in alternate caching methods later, such as Redis.